# WebRTC Error - Session error description: Data channel type mismatch. Expected RTP, got SCTP

Tags: webrtc, rtp, sctp

I am new to WebRTC and triyng to create my first app. I have found this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_quick_guide.htm and did as it was said there. The resulted app works fine if I test it in the Chrome. But when I try to test this app in 2 browser (Chrome and Mozilla) it gives me this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute
> 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Session error code:
> ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Data channel type mismatch.
> Expected RTP, got SCTP..

This happens when I send an offer from Mozilla client and Chrome client tries to give an answer to this offer in this part of code:

```
myConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
myConnection.createAnswer(function (answer) {
    myConnection.setLocalDescription(answer); 
    send({ 
        type: "answer", 
        answer: answer 
    }); 
}, function (error) { 
    alert("oops...error"); //<-- this alert fires all the time
});
```

I have googled this and all I have found is set `new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { optional: [{RtpDataChannels: false}] })` but if I do so then when I try to send a message it says that dataChannel.readyState is not openned.

What do I do wrong? Any help appriciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]` and then wait for the datachannel.onopen event to fire before attempting to send messages.

Comment: I did like that but datachannel.onopen never fires